# How reliable is the "smart" brake detection on a $20 tail light?

Tags: safety, lighting, led-lights, taillight

Here are some "smart" tail lights I found on Amazon:

[image: G Keni Smart Bike Tail Light, Brake Sensing Rear Lights, Ultra Bright LED Warning Bicycle Flashlight, USB Rechargeable, Auto On/Off Sensor, IPX6 Waterproof, Cycling Safety Back Taillight Accessories]
[image: Onvian Smart Bike Tail Light, USB Rechargeable Ultra Bright IPX6 Waterproof Brake Sensing Bicycle Rear Lights, Light Sense Rear Accessories Fits Any Road Bikes]
[image: EBUYFIRE Smart Bike Tail Light, USB Rechargeable,Intelligent Light Perception Bike Rear Light,4 Modes Ultra Bright Auto On/Off,IP65 Waterproof,Easy to Install for Any Bikes]
[image: Padonow Smart Bike Tail Light: Auto On/Off Flashing Lights Red Back Led Warning Flashlight Easy Mount Cycling Safety Warning Taillight USB Rechargeable Ultra Bright Light Sensing Bicycle Rear Light]
[image: JIRVYUK Tail Light for Bike, Brake Sensing Rear Lights, Ultra Bright LED Warning Bicycle Flashlight, USB Rechargeable, Auto On/Off Sensor, IPX5 Waterproof, LED Bicycle Tail Light for Any Road Bikes]

Having the same looks, prices, description grammar, no-name random "*brand*" names and sometimes even stock photos and videos, these seem like each-other's knock-offs coming from the same factory.

While I absolutely love the brake detection idea, should trust these with the technology and execution?

Or is there a bigger brand that introduced this idea that I should go for instead?

Comment: As a general rule: you only get for your money!

Comment: While I generally agree, I have no idea how much is $20 for this, with things getting cheaper, this could actually be an okay price?

Comment: What is brake detection and what do you expect it to do ?  How many rear lights do you plan on using?  And how often do you ride in a group or with other riders ?   I'd doubt this has any use for road users except other cyclists.

Comment: @Criggie here's [a video of it in action](https://amazon.com/vdp/1b05383ee69e4748bb947c05edbbe2ca) (the timestamp is 0:30). I was indeed considering it for the roads, and it actually looked helpful.

Comment: B&M has generator ones that work very well.

Comment: Its $20 so not a big cost - just get one and try it.  Run a second rear light of a different design as well - if one goes flat, fails, or falls off you probably won't notice.

Comment: $20 is still $20, plus I'm overseas, and returning back to Amazon in case it won't work is problematic.

Comment: If $20 is a problem and you don't have some kind of monopoly agreement with Amazon, why not order directly from Aliexpress?

Comment: I doubt the brake lights would be useful on a bicycle. Traffic signals work because most road users are essentially programmed to watch out for and respond to them, but nobody is watching out for braking (or turning) indicator lights on a bicycle. Maybe, just maybe if stuff like this becomes insanely popular in the future, things will be different.

Comment: On viewing your video, this product is really only of use in a group of cyclists.  If there's a car close enough behind you that brake warning makes a difference, then the car is far far too close.  It feels like a product looking for some kind of differentiation from the myriad of other lights out there.

Answer (score 4):

The brake detection is based on an accelerometer, and is not a complicated feature.  I have had a similar feature on a Chinese front light and it worked ok from what I can see. So that's probably not a key reason to buy a branded light instead.

---

Amazon are often parasitical in these products - AliExpress charges $11 for a similar (same?) thing
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000239342283.html

Cheap lights, especially tail lights can post a risk of death, in that I have purchased cheap lights from Amazon (albeit originally from China, similar to this), and they went out with no warning (battery dead) on a high-speed road.  (Though apparently some or all of the lights you link to have a battery indicator feature)

The biggest problem with these lights tends to be:

- small battery
- excessive brightness draining said battery
- lack of proper voltage-sensing battery indicator (about to die in 10 seconds is not good enough)

As a second light it would be ok, but I would not rely on it alone.

If you want a better product then a brand might well be better in several ways.

For example:

- https://www.cateye.com/intl/products/safety_lights/TL-NW100K/
- https://www.cateye.com/intl/products/safety_lights/TL-LD710K/
- https://ride.lezyne.com/collections/alert-led-lights
- https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/p/698001 - This is Garmin's actual radar light which gives you alerts for oncoming vehicles

The best quality light like you mention (and possibly the first) is made by Lupine:

https://www.lupine.de/products/tail-lights

The Rotlicht Max is 1680 mAh battery, the Rotlicht is 830 maAh

The AliX light is 420 mAh, the Cateye Sync is 500mAh and the cheaper model will be even less, and the Strip Drive Pro is 800 mAh.

Exposure are a similar quality brand to Lupine, and they have a 1500 mAh light

https://exposurelights.com/products/bike/rear-lights/blaze-mk3-reakt-peloton

and a 700 mAh light

https://exposurelights.com/products/bike/rear-lights/tracer-mk2-reakt-peloton

The Exposure & Lupine products are clearly much better than the AliX one, but they cost 10x as much, so they should be.

By paying for a brand you might get better build quality, better attachment mechanism, weather sealing , packaging, marketing, larger battery, better documentation, support videos, warranty and so on.

I don't think you could go too far wrong by buying one direct from China and then if it turns out to be inadequate then upgrading to a quality brand later. Or you could just go straight to quality now.

Comment: I've also had a Cateye (not cheap) rear light that went out going over bumps on skinny tyres, so it's not just the cheap ones that are risky. If you can't twist round enough to check, 2 rear lights is the way to go

Comment: Your points are fine and valid, but this is veering off into product rec which tend to expire quickly.

Comment: Rated battery capacity is only part of the story - I've had a name-brand computer last for years on a single coin cell.  A similar chinese one lasted two weeks on a pair of AAA.  So power draw is also a factor in life.

Comment: in general LEDs are pretty generic in that there's not going to be a significant difference in power consumption between brands (although front lights give fake '10,000' lumen figures, which are pure lies) for the same output. this is not really comparable to a computer, which could be using power constantly or some similar battery-chewing thing. So I wouldn't necessarily expect a big battery life difference, although again Chinese manufacturers are known to lie about their battery capacity, so 400 mAh could turn out to be 200, or something similar.

Comment: also it's not uncommon for one Chinese seller to say '400 mAh' and another to say '600 mAh', when in fact both are exactly the same internally; best to assume two identical-looking products are identical

Comment: -1 - Does not answer the question, which is about the reliability of the smart brake detection, not the reliability of the light.

Comment: It's the final paragraph. This is simple electronics. https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33061127985.html

Comment: My riding group almost exclusively uses Bontrager rear lights, which have this awesome ambient light sensor. The light’s brightness is always appropriate for the surrounding environment (saving battery), and they also kick up the brightness when car headlights shine at the light.

Comment: Missed that in the wall of product recommendations.

Comment: @mattnz fair point - the main answer should be in the first paragraph, which I've done just now.